# Firebase Analytics and Google Tag Manager : <FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Event name is reserved

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I integrated Firebase and GTM over cocoapods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0'
```

Podfile.lock for the versions used :

> - Firebase/Core (3.12.0):
>
>   - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.6.0)
>   - FirebaseCore (= 3.4.7)
> - FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0):
>
>   - FirebaseCore (~> 3.4)
>   - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
>   - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
> - FirebaseCore (3.4.7):
>
>   - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
> - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
> - GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
> - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
>
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
> - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
> - GoogleTagManager (5.0.8):
>
>   - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.0)
>   - GoogleAnalytics (~> 3.0)
>   - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.3.0)
> - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.1)
> - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.1):
>
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
> - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
>
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)

and followed the steps in documentation for the integration but i am having these warnings :

```
<FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Event name is reserved. Ignoring event: user_engagement
<FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Event name is reserved. Ignoring event: first_open
```

I know these are reserved events so i am not sending these. Can there an integration problem between GTM and firebase Analytics?

**EDIT**

I removed the ".json" extension from the config file. Logs said :

```
GoogleTagManager warning: No default container found. Container needs to be added to a container folder and added to the target.
Configuration was not found in database. The configuration will be fetched from the network when necessary
Firebase Analytics is ready to receive events
Firebase Analytics enabled
Fetching configuration from the server
Downloading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:...
Successful fetched configuration from the server. Got network response. Code, size: 200, 106
Successfully parsed a configuration. Version: 1484056.........
Measurement data sent to network
Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, 0
```

any ideas ???

but errors are gone ???

Any ideas

Comment: If you take out GTM, does the error go away? If so, it is probably the problem of the integration of the SDKs

Comment: Yes it is gone.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because of including files in a wrong way. Just be sure to include container folder properly. A tip : folder icon color shall be blue in project navigator.

Comment: Please, could you explain hoe the folder icon can be made blue. Add a tip that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To a folder in Xcode 11>, simply create the folder and drag it into your XCode and check `Create folder reference` in the import wizard popup. You will have the folder with a blue colour in the project navigator.